# 3 Logos not disappearing with responsive navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I've tried everything to make my 3 logos disappear when the browser becomes mobile friendly.  Instead they just float around the screen.  I've tried placing my images before, after, and all sorts of places in between of my navbar code:

```
    <header id="header">
<div id="headerbg"></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">

        <a class="brand"></a>
        <img class="appstore" src="img/apple.png"></img>
        <img class="appstore" src="img/googleplay.png"></img>

        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>

        <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">

            <ul id="nav" class="nav">
                <li><a href="#home" class="active">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#features">features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#signup">signup</a></li>
                <!-- portfolio link not needed <li><a href="#portfolio">portfolio</a></li> -->
                <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

You can see my site here [.com](http://instamour.com)

And if you make the browser small, you will notice the navbar menu icon shows up, and if you click it, my logos for , google store, apple store, are floating everywhere.  This is driving me nuts.  I've searched bootstrap, stack overflow, google, and other sites to try and figure this out.  I am using Twitter Bootstrap obviously for this site.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, I inspected your website with Google webtools, and when I simply add **class 'hidden-phone'** (= the class you need to add to elements to hide them in bootstrap) to the relevant links/ images, they disappear as expected.

Comment: aahh this worked!! Thanks so much!  I didn't know the hidden-phone attribute....well....now I do thanks to you!

Comment: I guess the real question now is how to keep my logo to the left of the nav menu icon visible when I am in "mobile" mode.  That's another tricky question I can't figure out.

Comment: You mean, that it shouldn't jump down? You can use media queries for that and set the margin-left (which is 60px currently) to be less or none when screen size is smaller than , eg 480px.